# Error while taking input for file transfer

Tags: java, exception, input, user-input

My task was to send file through `socket`. I was prompting for how many files to be sent. But it was always throwing `exception`.

here is the code:

```
public void soc_server() throws IOException {
    servsock = new ServerSocket(55000);
    sock = servsock.accept();
    System.out.println("Hello Server");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    **System.out.println("how many files to be sent: ");
    String temp = sc.nextLine();
    // i used to take integer here. Still it was throwing same exception.
    int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    sc.close();
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);**
    for (int x = 0; x < fileNumber; x++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name or file path ");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        File file = new File(s);
        if (file.exists())
            System.out.println("File found");
        else
            System.out.println("File not found");
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(s);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        System.out.println("sending file no: " + x);
        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalSent += bytesRead;
                System.out.println("sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " KB "
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000)
                        + " sec");
            }
        }
        out.flush();
        fileInputStream.close();
        // sock.close();
        out.close();
        // servsock.close();
        // servsock = new ServerSocket(55000);
        // sock = servsock.accept();
        pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
        pw.print(s);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
    sock.close();
    servsock.close();
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("Sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " kilobytes in "
            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000) + " seconds");
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Server.soc_server(Server.java:41)
at Index.main(Index.java:21)
```

Except the prompt line of how many files are going to be sent over, the rest of the code work well. I am really confused over why I am getting the same exception while I am writing:

```
String temp = sc.nextLine();
int fileNumber = sc.nextInt();
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing?

Comment: show us the rest of your code

Comment: Why don't you use `Integer temp=sc.nextInt();`? I don't think this solves your problem. But to make more short. And why scanner is closing and creating again?

Comment: I thought it wont throw the exception if I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate the Scanner at the start of your code:
Remove  below lines

```
    sc.close();
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I did this. it did not made any difference. Because I initialized the scanner before the method starts. After taking input from temp, i closed the scanner to check if it makes any difference.

Comment: In my end, its taking an extra space which is adding to the next file name input.
will you send me over your code? the particular input taking line please? @Sach

Comment: You can trim it then :)